# Can you not apply $\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$ to the series $\sum^{n+1}_{k=0}\binom{n+1}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

If you have the series $\sum^{n+1}_{k=0}\binom{n+1}{k}$, and apply $\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$, then it would become $\sum^{n+1}_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}+\sum^{n+1}_{k=0}\binom{n}{k-1}$, but $\binom{n}{n+1}$ is not defined, and it is the last term in $\sum^{n+1}_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}$, so what happens then? Is this a valid thing to do?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Rather than being undefined, $\binom{n}{r}=0$ for $r>n$, because there are no size-$r$ subsets of a size-$n$ set. You can treat $r<0$ similarly.

Comment: so you can turn $\sum^{n+1}_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}$ into $\sum^{n}_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: Of course not: you forgot the second term, $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom n{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom n{k-1}=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj=2^n.$ To summarize: $2^{n+1}=2^n+2^n.$ Btw, I wouldn't call that a "series" (in the title and body of your post), but a sum. I may be wrong but I believe that "series" means *infinite* sum.

Comment: You can define $\binom{n}{k}=0$ for $k>n$ and $k<0,$ and you still get the recurrence for $\binom{n+1}k.$

Comment: Yes, that was explained in J.G.'s comment.